# How do I run separate ActionScript 3 class code in a Flash project?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to create some sort of game prototype using ActionScript 3. 
However, I have run into something that could be called a Catch-22.

```
package Main{
public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
    public function Main()
    {
        //gameLoop()
        StartGame()
    }
    public function StartGame()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop)
    }
    var spr = new Symbol6();
    public function gameLoop(e:Event):void
    {
        addChild(Symbol6)
        trace("owo")
    }
        //new Bullet(0,0,5,Math.PI,0,5,0,0)
    }
}
```

The code above outputs:

> 1037: Packages cannot be nested.

And if I were to remove the `package Main` block, it would output

> 1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.

How am I supposed to solve this?

Comment: I assume you pasted the script above into the frame?

Comment: I didn't paste the script into the frame, It's a separate .as3 file

Comment: Well, it did worth ruling out. So, how do you use it in your project then? Via **import** or **include**?

Comment: I used `include`.

Comment: @kot32 have you tried to remove "Main" after "package"? you don't want to use the same name for the package and the class.  What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: @kot32 Ah, that's it. The **include** directive loads the whole file content into the place where **include** line is placed. Literally, it is the same as pasting it into the frame, you are not using that class as class. Packages are, simply, folder hierarchy where your .as files reside. I think you should read (in given order) this https://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/classes_as3_pg1.htm and this https://community.adobe.com/t5/animate/how-do-i-get-external-classes-to-work-in-as3-sample-included/td-p/2592552 for some understanding.